What Example of Guizot in 'Les Partis Politique' of Maurice Duverger refers to?
in the introduction of 'Les Partis Politique' by Maurice Duverger, in the introduction, the authors refer to Guizot as quote:

On sait l'importance que ces  phénomènes de corruptions prennent dans une certaine
phase du développement démocratique, comme moyen pour le gouvernement de résister à
une pression croissantedes  assemnlées : les exemples de  Guizot en  France  et  de
Giolitti en Italie sont présent dans toutes les mémoires.

translated as:

We know the importance that these phenomena of corruption take in a certain
phase of  democratic  development,  as a  means for the government to resist
increasing pressure from the assemblies: the examples of Guizot in France and
Giolitti in Italy are present in all memories.

I did some research on Guizot but I am not sure what event should be according to Duverger "present in my memory"

Presumably, Guizot's ban on poliical meetings (Paris banquets) that led to the revolution of 1848
